# How to get the latest version of Google Maps InfoWindow?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to make infoWindows a little less uglier I found out that the infoWindows on Google Maps and the infoWindows created through API are different.

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJOpY.png)

Do I have to style infoWindows manually or it's possible to get those stylish ones through API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API does not provide for easy, direct, robust styling of the InfoWindow objects (or, if it does, it is not documented) except for a few small things.  You can see what options are available at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions.  As you can see, right now, there's nothing for things like rounded corners vs. not-rounded corners, etc.   (Side question: What do you call corners that aren't rounded?)

So, sorry to say, it would seem like you are stuck messing with stylesheets, at least at the current time.  Or you could use http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js as a starting point but that may be a lot of code for a small effect.